# Ado.net stored procedure inserts does not show on EF Code First queries instantly

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In our system we have implemented custom ADO.NET data imports with stored procs to our database because the performance of EF Code First and Linq2Sql isn't really good enough for the amount of data we have to process.

The problem is that once the import job has completed it will still take several minutes to get the new data showing up on our views when it is queried with Code First DbContext and objects.

We are not using any custom caches or OutputCaches so the only thing caching the results must be EF itself. We are using Dependency injection on out MVC controllers to get service instance that provides the datamodel for the view. The scope is set to be per request so the service instances should be recreated once request hits that controller action, right?

Basically our services are deriving from the following base class that initializes the correct context.

```
public class ServiceBase<T> : IDisposable
    where T : DbContext, new()
{
    private T _context;

    protected ServiceBase()
    {
        this._context = new T();
    }
}
```

On our context we have set the Autodetectchanges to false

```
Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
```

Also we are reloading our objectcontext entities after the imports job like this

```
var refreshableObjects = ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager
            .GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Deleted | EntityState.Modified | EntityState.Unchanged)
            .Where(o => o.EntityKey != null).Select(o => o.Entity);

ObjectContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, refreshableObjects);
```

But it is not working. I have tried to look up information on how to properly reload the DbContext but have not yet figured it out. Everywhere it says that disposing the context and recreating it should clear the cache but it doesn't seem to work.

Could someone help me? Much thanks!

Comment: you dont want entity framework to cache your results?

Comment: When you use EF it by default loads each entity only once per context. The first query creates entity instace and stores it internally. Any subsequent query which requires entity with the same key returns this stored instance. If values in the data store changed you still receive the entity with values from the initial query

Comment: The caching is great as long as it is easily flushed. Right now I don't have a clue how to flush it. Isn't the context recreated always per request meaning that once I refresh the page I should get the most recent data from database instead of the cached entities?

Answer (score 0):

If you know that changes happened outside of EF and want to refresh your ctxt for a specific entity, you can call [ObjectContext.Refresh](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896255.aspx)

```
datamodel.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, orders);
```

If this seems like it will be a common occurance, you should disable object caching in your queries:

```
SchoolBriefcaseEntities datamodel = new SchoolBriefcaseEntities();
datamodel.tblCities.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;
```

or for to turn off object level caching for specific Entity,

```
Context.Set<Compliances>().AsNoTracking();
```

Comment: We are calling ObjectContext.Refresh after the import as mentioned in the question but that does not seem to work. I don't want to disable the cache I just want to reset it after our data import is complete.

Comment: @suomiton check this article http://www.bfcamara.com/post/37112709703/ef5-entity-framework-cache-problems